# What is major different between favicon,fav-icon and icon 2022?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html5-canvas

I know about favicon. `<link rel="favicon" href="#" type="image/png">`.
In this code favicon is a small image for a website that denotes the page Brand that can help to identify the original page. In other words, a favicon is a short icon or tab icon, or URL icon that contains 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels.
[Here I saw three favicon link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekaRt.png).
please guide me the different between these three `<link rel="fav-icon" href="#" type="image/png">` `<link rel="favicon" href="#" type="image/png">` `<link rel="icon" href="#" type="image/png">`.

Comment: Where did you find favicon and fav-icon used for rel attribute value? I don’t recognise them and can’t find them in the specs.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred and valid rel attribute value for favicon or an icon representing the current document is `rel="icon"`. The other two in your post are not a valid one

```
<link rel="icon" href="#" type="image/png">
```

Sometimes `rel="shortcut icon"` is also used, but this link type is non-conforming, ignored and web authors must not use it anymore. [Here is the official documentation link to read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Comment: What's the use of `href='#'` to represent an icon? Shouldn't it be the URL of an image?